# Can this LabVIEW program be easily ported to Python to forward on sensor data to a server?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, labview

I have a Labview program written by someone else. A snippet from LabVIEW:

[LabVIEW Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEuXn.png)

[CompactDAQ Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlBfQ.png)

There are strain gauges, connected to CompactDAQ modules, which are then connected to a laptop via ethernet. 
I think I have this right, in that it's a simple program that is sampling the sensors every second through the loggers, and writing that to CSV.

(However, in order to extract the data, the program must be stopped, the CSV file written, and set running again. On top of this, it requires a dedicated laptop to run, and since I actually need the data live minute by minute, is not the best solution.)

I want to replace the laptop with a Raspberry Pi, and feed the data live to a server, porting the application to Python or whatever is the best coding language to use (I only suggest python because I at least know a little bit about it).

My question:

1) Which coding language, based on your experience, is the better one to use for this?

2) Have I understood things correctly?

3) Is my thinking that "all" I need to do is to get the Raspberry to talk to the loggers, and then direct whatever it receives from them to an API in the form of a string, the correct approach to retrieving the data?

(I hope this is a better way of asking?)

*EDIT

Ok so it seems that what I am trying to achieve is not possible. The drivers and libraries needed to make the NI kit work are huge and reside on the host machine, I had mistakenly believed that I could simply read what was coming in on ethernet and forward this on, but it seems that is not the case.

If anyone knows different, please speak up!

Comment: Hi - StackOverflow is a bit different in that it is a question answer site, and not a discussion forum. Please avoid open-ended questions. See the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for more.

Comment: Ok no worries. Sorry. I'll take this one down.

Comment: You could probably edit the question to be more specific ('what are the issues involved in porting this application to Python') rather than delete it altogether.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the question a bit to better fit what we now know about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Either study LabVIEW yourself, or pay somebody else to convert the code.

If studying yourself, picking up a good **book**: [Travis and Kring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131856723) for one and understanding dataflow is a good start.

You may get some help if you install the [LabVIEW C generator module](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/209015)  which supposedly translates LabVIEW to C. However, to get a qualified translation, and understanding what it means, you have to have LabVIEW qualified person to set up the C generator, use it and explain the result limitations.

Comment: I'm looking and studying Labview myself to work out what it is actually doing, it seems as though it is simply cranking out the values from the sensors every second into a CSV. As I look deeper, I think this could well be fairly straight forward. Thanks for the link to the C generator, that's a big help!

Comment: Posting an LV diagram, and/or rephrasing the question might help

Comment: I'm not sure what the availability of the C generator is but if you can get it I'm pretty sure it'll be expensive - NI would prefer you to deploy your code to their own embedded hardware, obviously.

Comment: Posted a diagram.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible. I've used LabView and in my opinion it is nice for three reasons. First it is good for communicating with devices, especially National Instruments own data acquisition hardware, but also other instruments. There are a lot of prewritten subVIs (LabView for functions) that make this easier. You'll have to figure out that syntax for yourself in Python. Second, LabView makes user interfaces really easy. This doesn't seem to be a big deal for you. Lastly, LabView is interesting in that processes wired in parallel execute in parallel. This can be real handy and may be tougher to emulate in Python without threads. This also doesn't seem to be important for you. Python, I think is much better for processing text. There is a debugging mode in LabView where it steps visually through the program that can be really helpful figuring out what is going on. Look for a little lightbulb icon.

Looking at the recent additions to your question, it seems you are trying to work with a National Instruments CompactDAQ device. National Instruments provides several software interfaces to their devices along with an API (mostly PC centric). Since LabView hides a lot of this from you, you may need to look at National Instruments support pages for support information. In particular I'd look at this [page](http://forums.ni.com/t5/NI-Labs-Toolkits/Low-Cost-USB-DAQ-Driver-for-use-with-Raspberry-Pi/ta-p/3533944) where I think you will find a driver specifically for use on a Raspberry Pi. In addition, this [page](https://www.tsxperts.com/labviewforraspberrypi/) suggests there will soon be a LabView for Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thank you very much! :o) 

There are reasons for using the python script, and not labview (namely, I need the data to be forwarded on without a whole laptop sitting there doing it, a discreet Raspberry Pi that can do it "live" is much better).

It doesn't need to be user friendly, it will never be viewed. I see what you mean about parallel threads. Ultimately though I have three devices giving a varying resistance measurement feeding to a logger each. That is then aggregated into one feed to a laptop using Labview. So... Figuring out the syntax for the loggers will be fun... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The original question didn't mention that the LabVIEW code uses NI-DAQmx functions. Since it turns out that it does, I believe it would not be a trivial task for a beginner programmer to port to Python on a Windows platform and as far as I know it is impossible to do this on a Raspberry Pi.

If there were no dependencies on DAQmx or similar libraries however, Python on a Raspberry Pi should be fine - or you might want to look at [MicroPython](http://micropython.org/), perhaps running on a board such as the [WiPy](https://www.pycom.io/solutions/py-boards/wipy2/). You may or may not have to use multithreading dependent on how much data your loggers transmit and how quickly - it may be OK to use a loop that checks each port in turn for incoming data, adds it to a queue and processes it whenever a complete reading has been received, if the serial port buffers are adequate to hold any new data that comes in in the meantime. If your loggers only transmit in response to a command from the host then there should be no need for multithreading, just query them each in turn.

In either case, LabVIEW or Python, you should try to get started and ask a more specific question if you need further help.

If you were familiar with LabVIEW, or wanted a project to develop your LabVIEW skills on, there is a [third-party add-on](https://www.tsxperts.com/labviewforraspberrypi/) that lets you deploy LabVIEW code to the Pi, but this costs extra and doesn't support all LabVIEW functions - in particular you would need to check how far it supports parallel execution if that is important. (For reference, the Home Edition of LabVIEW can deploy non-GUI run-time code to the Raspberry Pi 2/3, but this is only licenced for personal use not for commercial or academic applications.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, it is very much appreciated. Please believe me when I say that I am researching as I type. I tend to ask as I research, that way if I draw a blank there's a good chance that I will have something to read from someone far more knowledgeable than me. I have started writing a script to do exactly as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated question shows that the data is being collected by NI CompactDAQ modules that are connected to the host PC by Ethernet.

This being the case it will be much, much easier for you to update the existing LabVIEW software than to rewrite it in another language. It is possible to call NI-DAQmx functions (NI's data acquisition library) from languages other than LabVIEW, but I don't think that's a trivial task for a beginner programmer. In any case I'm almost certain there is currently no way to work with CompactDAQ on a Raspberry Pi or other similar low-cost boards.

The good news however is that assuming the actual data acquisition side of things is working OK at the moment, it shouldn't be too hard to update your LabVIEW program to do what you want. Currently you pass the array of numeric readings (the orange wire) into a **case structure** containing a **subVI** which I assume saves the data to disk:

[image: case structure from OP's example code]

Instead of this subVI I would use a **queue** to send this data out of the acquisition loop. I would then add a second loop to the diagram whose job is to wait for data on the queue and do whatever you want to do with it - this could be writing it to a file, sending it to a server, or whatever you prefer. A queue buffers the data so that if your 'consumer' loop has to wait for network or file access, it won't interfere with the running of the 'producer' loop.

You'll need to add a mechanism for stopping both loops when you want to exit the program, as a single 'stop' button on its own won't work cleanly with more than one loop. Also your code doesn't currently do any error handling - I would definitely want to see some error wires on the diagram with some code to catch and handle error conditions such as a communications failure or disk error.

This is not difficult LabVIEW but like anything there will be a learning curve if you're a beginner. The tutorials, examples and templates included with LabVIEW should cover everything you need for this but if you get stuck NI offer LabVIEW training face-to-face or online or you could get in touch with a NI alliance partner (find one via the NI site) to arrange some consultancy.

Finally if you really want to cut the laptop out of the system and make this a more robust, standalone setup then you could move this code on to something like a compactRIO system (which can use the same modules as the cDAQ) using LabVIEW Real-Time. I wouldn't recommend trying to make that leap yourself right now given you're starting from the beginning with LabVIEW but it would be an option for the future and would re-use most of your existing code.

Comment: I'm not in front of LabVIEW right now so couldn't open the snippet to see inside the subVI or post my own snip of it as a VI snippet - I'll edit this in later on if I get the chance.

Comment: Thank you VERY much for your time, it is really appreciated!
And thank you even more for demonstrating the best way forward here. This is the point where I'd buy you a beverage of some sort haha! 

I shall take all that ^ and see what I can do with it.